# .htaccess ignored when url contains encoded forward slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I encountered some really strange behaviour in Apache. I have a standard *"let PHP handle everything which isn't a file or directory"* rewrite setup.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This works as expected *except* when the URL contains `%2F`, which is an encoded forward slash (/). Whenever this happens, Apache responds with a 404, which is logical since none of these paths exists. But what I can't understand, is why my rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` are being ignored.

TL;DR

`GET /Foo/bar/baz` is served by my PHP-script

`GET /Foo/bar%2Fbaz` is served by Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer myself. The config directive `AllowEncodedSlashes` must be set to `on` for this to work. Otherwise, Apache will respond with a 404 when the URL contains an encoded forward slash or backslash.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: This looks like a bad default behavior. It only makes sense to distinguish `%2F` from `/` in a URI scheme where this reserved character is to be used for an alternate special purpose. This is going to be the exception rather than the rule, and when such a scheme occurs in an app, the usage will likely be in the query part of the URL following a `?` character.